# How can I get data to be sent over sockets infinitely every certain amount of time?

Tags: python, loops, sockets, micropython

I am sending data with sockets from the client to my server. The problem I have is that it sends it only once and never again, I need it to loop sending it every 2 minutes

```
port = 8000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("",port))

print('Puerto en', ip)

while True:
    ph=phsensor()
    start_counter = 1
    sleep (1)
    start_counter = 0
    caudal = (count * 60 * 2.25 / 1000)
    print("El caudal es: %.3f L/min" % (caudal))
    count = 0
    sleep (5)
    if caudal < 1:
        print("No esta llegando suficiente agua")
        led1.value(1)
    else:
        led1.value(0)
    if caudal > 2:
        print("El agua esta circulando bien")
    data=';'.join([str(caudal),str(ph)]).encode('utf-8')
    s.send(data)
    dataFromServer = s.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Is the server actually sending anything in response to the data it receives?  That `.recv()` at the end is going to block until the server sends something.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me give you some advice:

- First of all: When you are using sockets or another I/O peripheral, **never sleep the thread where the operation of I/O is running**, because you will block the peripheral and it will bring you several problems of performance. Let me share a [link](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-time-sleep?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=1455363063&utm_adgroupid=65083631748&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=278443377086&utm_targetid=dsa-429603003980&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=1010095&gclid=Cj0KCQjwiNSLBhCPARIsAKNS4_d6gQRmoZ1BD2dqsFMsDPNPGMPDH7Q8ycqo1ROQqrig2pWiElkcTPkaApRhEALw_wcB) to use the `Thread.sleep` in python.
- Second: The code that you share shows that your program is uni-threading and you are using `sleep`, which breaks the first point. I recommend you to use threads, here you have a [link](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) to know how to use them.
- Third: Try to create a main thread that is always running, no matter if it waiting for a signal, like pressing a key or another event. The second thread will have the task to check the time to call the send method.

Those are my recommendation, I hope you can solve your problem or homework.